# Why isn't the word "Which" one of the 5 Wh-question words?

Tags: wh-questions

Wikipedia has a nice history article on the 5 question words beginning with "Wh" namely,

> Who, What, Where, When, and Why

But nothing on the word "Which."  Could this be just tradition?

Comment: The article which I think you are referring to says ; "The Five Ws (sometimes referred to as Five Ws and How, 5W1H, or Six Ws)[1] are questions whose answers are considered _basic in information gathering or problem solving_. They are often mentioned in journalism" There are a host of _[interrogative_ words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word)...including which.

Comment: There are many different versions of this list.

Comment: There's an old poem about this, but I can't find it on Google.

Comment: @HotLicks Kipling's "I keep six honest serving men".

Comment: @KateBunting - Yep: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/413263-i-keep-six-honest-serving-men-i-keep-six

Comment: "Which" seems supplemental in that it presupposes that the answer to "What" is ambiguous. In other words, if "What" (and perhaps "Who" and "Where" and the others) are answered clearly, then there's typically no need to ask "Which".

Comment: I suspect that the original selection of these words came from Kipling's poem, and his choices were in part poetic.  So there's likely no "logical" reason.

Comment: Wikipedia is not an authoritative source on grammar. Why they left _which_ out of their survey could no doubt be answered by an author. There are considerable grammar differences between _which_ and the other _wh_-words, but that's true of all of them. By the way, did they include _whether_ among the _wh_-words? They should have.

Comment: @JohnLawler: And *whither* and *whence*? :)

Comment: @psmears Not to mention _wherefore_…

Comment: @psmears _Wh_-words come from PIE _*kʷ_-words, and constitute part of [an old paradigm in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.pdf). They include _whither_ and _whence_, the PIE _*t_-words include _thither_ and _thence_, and the PIE _*k_-words include _hither_ and _hence_. There was a lot of stuff going on.

Comment: related on Latin.SE: [What's up with _ubi_?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/whats-up-with-ub%c4%ab)

Comment: @JohnLawler: Thanks - I'm aware of that, that's why I mentioned them :) By the way I think there may be a few typos in your PDF in the "filia" paradigm: I think "fialiae" should be "filiae", and the ablative should be "filiis" or "filiabus" not "filii"?

Comment: You're the first to notice them, after me. Luckily, I'm retired.

Comment: Like vowels, "why" could sort of count but isn't included.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia is not an authoritative source on grammar, as John Lawler has pointed out. That said, it can be useful to point in the general direction for research.

Also, as Hot Licks mentioned, Kipling seems to be in the equation.

> I keep six honest serving-men, 
> (They taught me all I knew);
> Their names are What and Why and When
> And How and Where and Who.

However, the origin of the 5(6)  Ws  goes back to Latin "7 Qs"…in which the  English Wh word is *usually*  a Latin Qu…

*Quis* = Who

*Quid* = What

*Cur* =  Why

*Ubi* = Where

*Quando* = When

*Quem ad  modem* = How

*Quibus ad miniculis* = **With what*...*

“Which” in Latin is *Quod*, and that does not appear in the original list.

The original 7 Qs were important in the discussion  of ethics. Thomas Aquinas attributed them to Aristotle. More recently, they have been considered one of the basic tenets of effective journalism.

So, while Kipling may appear to be the origin of the selection, it is much older than that, and was  probably included as part of the English public school  (AmE private school) education. Kipling’s own education seems to have been a bit spotty;
he probably picked up the idea from his mates at the newspapers he started his career with.

Comment: Latin is not my strong suit, so if anyone would like to offer constructive criticism go ahead...or even edit.

Comment: Note the prevalence of QU's in Latin and of WH's in English. This is not an accident. Both are derived from the same PIE roots, which started with *kʷ- for the most part. This persisted in Latin but Grimm's Law changed *kʷ to *hʷ in Germanic, which we eventually wound up spelling WH in Modern English (it was spelled HW in Old English).

Answer (score 8):

[Which](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/which) means to

> used in questions and structures in which there is **a fixed or limited set** of answers or possibilities) what one or ones

Hence, it would be a supplement to the other ones.  If John bought a cat in Springfield, you could ask which John, which cat, and which Springfield.

Comment: Not to mention that if John bought a cat from a woman on a broomstick in Springfield, you could also ask which witch.

Comment: The question isn't about the way in which 'which' is used, rather about the reason/s for its non-inclusion in certain listings among other interrogative words (and 'how' is often considered a 'wh-word').

Comment: … and whether it is even possible for a person to truly own a cat.    :-)    ⁠